# Clicking on a specific button on the website using powershell

Tags: html, forms, powershell

I'm trying to click in link, but nothing happens. Help please! Where did I make a mistake?

*My OS ,PS and IE versions:*

```
PS Z:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117

PS Z:\> gcim Win32_OperatingSystem | select caption,CSDVersion,version,OSArchitecture

caption                               CSDVersion     version  OSArchitecture
-------                               ----------     -------  --------------
Microsoft Windows 7 Профессиональная  Service Pack 1 6.1.7601 64-bit

PS Z:\> (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer').svcVersion
11.0.9600.18738
```

[I can not click on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D12g3.jpg)

Here is an output of the powershell commands which shows the element I need to click:

```
PS Z:\> $ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_ibInsert").outerHTML

    <input name="ctl00$CPH$NP2$gvUserNotepads$ctl06$ibInsert" id="ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_ibInsert" style="border
    -width: 0px; background-color: transparent;" onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptio
    ns("ctl00$CPH$NP2$gvUserNotepads$ctl06$ibInsert", "", true, "Insert", "", false, false))' type="image" alt="Добавить" sr
    c="../../../Images/b_add.gif">

PS Z:\> $ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_ibInsert") | select Type, Name, ID

    type  name                                        id
    ----  ----                                        --
    image ctl00$CPH$NP2$gvUserNotepads$ctl06$ibInsert ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_ibInsert
```

Here are my attempts:

```
1) $Link = $ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_ibInsert") | where-object {$_.type -eq "image"}
   $Link.click();
2) $ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_ibInsert").click()
```

**Here is the powershell code.You can test it yourself (login/pass are real):**

```
$userlogin = "all"
$userpasswd = "1234567"
$loginpage = "http://aszp.gaz-is.ru/aszp2/Autorization/ASZPLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2faszp2%2fDefault.aspx"
$notepad = "http://aszp.gaz-is.ru/aszp2/ARMs/CreateRequest/Notepads/Notepads.aspx"
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $false
$ie.Navigate2($loginpage)
While ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400 }
$forms = $ie.Document.forms.namedItem("form1")
$forms.item("Login1_UserName").value= $userlogin
$forms.item("Login1_Password").value = $userpasswd
$ie.document.getElementById("Login1_Button1").click()
While ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400 }
$ie.navigate($notepad)
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }
$forms2 = $ie.Document.forms.namedItem("aspnetForm")
$forms2.item("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_txtTEI1").value= "Petrov"
$forms2.item("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_txtTEI2").value = "Ivan"
$forms2.item("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_txtTEI3").value = "Nikolaevich"
$forms2.item("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_txtTEI6").value = "Driver"
$forms2.item("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_txtTEI8").value = "photo_321"
$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_ibInsert").click()
While ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400 }
$ie.Visible = $true
```

[**Here is the link to my server where the simplified code is. Everything works on it**](https://allovergeorgia.com/vk/form/input.html)

Example powershell code for my link:

```
$loginpage = "https://allovergeorgia.com/vk/form/input.html"
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate2($loginpage)
While ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400 }
$ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_ibInsert").click()
$ie.Document.Body.InnerText
```

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Instead post an answer, accept that answer when you can and that will tell others that the question is now solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.
It was necessary to look at the full picture. Sending the form was allowed only when all required fields was filled in.

I forgot about the phone number field: `$forms2.item("ctl00_CPH_NP2_gvUserNotepads_ctl06_txtTEIP7_tx‌​tEAEBDD").value = "911"`

After it was added to the code, everything was fine and the code worked))